# Execute a copy command using a batch file by opening CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I'm creating a batch file on my desktop which has a simple code:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe
```

This will open up Command Prompt.

Then I need to copy paste following code into the command prompt.

```
for /r "Z:\QCQA\Main QCQA Files\QA System Files\Nonconformance\Non-Conformance Reports\" %i in (NCR*.pdf) do copy "%~fi" "Z:\QCQA\Main QCQA Files\QA System Files\Nonconformance\NCR Log Tracking\PDF Destination from DOS\" /Y
```

The above command simply copies and pastes PDFs from one directory to another directory.

Is there a way to write the entire thing into a batch file? 
Desired output is:

- A Desktop Icon of a BAT File.
- Double clicking on it will do two things: Open up Command Prompt and Executes the Copy command.
- Closes the Command Prompt once done

Once that's done, I can simply use Windows Task Scheduler to run this Bat file everyday at 5:00 AM.

All the helps are appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: create a batchfile, then create a shortcut to it. (Don't schedule the shortcut, but the actual batch file. Note: when you start a batch file as a scheduled task, you need to take some precautions (working folder, be sure the network drive is connected [`Z:` suggests a network drive])

Comment: Why would you need this after all? To me this looks like a classical [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)…

Comment: executing a `.bat` or `.cmd` file opens a `cmd` instance automatically. No need to execute `cmd.exe` explicitely.

Comment: I apologize guys, if the question is inappropriate. I am just a new guy here.

Comment: @aschipfl Some human needs to go to Command Prompt every day in the morning and copy paste "for r/..." code and execute it manually. If I've a batch file which does that automatically when double clicking on it, then I can schedule it to run at 5:00 AM everyday.

Comment: Alright, but this does not need to copy code into a Command Prompt window, you just need a batch file, and that is it… By the way: please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)…

Answer (score 0):

- Create a batch file on the desktop and use the following code...

```
@echo off

for /r "Z:\QCQA\Main QCQA Files\QA System Files\Nonconformance\Non-Conformance Reports\" %%i in (NCR*.pdf) do (
  copy "%%i" "Z:\QCQA\Main QCQA Files\QA System Files\Nonconformance\NCR Log Tracking\PDF Destination from DOS\" /Y
)
```

- Double Click on the batch file anytime you want to run it.
- That's it! =)

Comment: You should perhaps make sure that the network location `Z:` really exists; what about referring to the target directly (using `pushd`/`popd`)?